# Open desktop application by Angular or Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, firefox

So the main problem i'm encountering right now is that I'm trying to open a Firefox from Chrome with a click of a button. I did try window.open(URL) but that opens up another Chrome window..

So is there any way to open any desktop application from the browser by using Angular or javascript?

Comment: Angular is a JavaScript library, not an alternative to JS. It can't do anything JS can't do.

Comment: Yes I know that's why I said both, but do you have an answer to my question by any chance?